# Autolayout and strange UItableView display

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to add 3 UItableviews to a viewcontroller view using IB and adding auto layout constraints to achieve the following conditions:

- space between tableviews and borders = 20
- space between tableviews = 20
- Equal tableviews widths

when I run the app on the simulator, I get a strange behavior. The tableviews seem to be positioned correctly, behave as expected during rotations, but the content of one of them is always shifted down...

it looks like a space above the header that I can't explain and remove...

Any ideas ?

Thx.

H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the top constraint to the first table view and bottom constraint to last tableview in the view controller and in the middle tableview assign top and bottom constraint as vertical spacing between the table views and height as less priority. It may work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the tableview are not stacked. There is a left, a right and a center tableview

Comment: You can try the same approach as i suggested above vertical constraint will be converted to horizontal constraint for the middle table view , Top - to leading constraint to left most table view and bottom to trailing space for the right most table view